# ¿Cuál es la verdadera utilidad de los métodos mágicos __set y __get en PHP?

Tags: php, poo

Respondiendo a una pregunta aquí mismo descubrí [este interesante comentario](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.overloading.php#119898) en el Manual de PHP, en el cual se demuestra la pasmosa facilidad con la que se puede violar la *encapsulación*  de objetos en PHP.

En efecto, si creo mi objeto así:

```
class Objeto {

    private $id;
    private $propertyOne;
    private $propertyTwo;

   function __construct() {
   }

    public function setPropertyOne ($propertyOne) {
        $this->propertyOne=$propertyOne;
    }

   public function getPropertyOne () {
        return $this->propertyOne;
    }

    public function setPropertyTwo ($propertyTwo) {
        $this->propertyTwo=$propertyTwo;
    }

   public function getPropertyTwo () {
        return $this->propertyTwo;
    }    

}
```

Es posible violar la *encapsulación* de una forma totalmente ingenua:

```
$myObjeto=new Objeto();
$myObjeto->fakeProperty='Esta propiedad no existía y se creará arbitrariamente';
var_dump($myObjeto);
```

**Salida:**

```
  object(Objeto)#1 (4) {
  ["id":"Objeto":private]=>
  NULL
  ["propertyOne":"Objeto":private]=>
  NULL
  ["propertyTwo":"Objeto":private]=>
  NULL
  ["fakeProperty"]=>
  string(55) "Esta propiedad no existía y se creará arbitrariamente"
}
```

Ahí está, la no deseada `fakeProperty` haciendo parte de mi objeto.

En el mismo comentario se indica un modo de usar el método máginco `__set` para evitar esa violación de la *encapsulación*:

```
    public function __set($k, $v) {
       throw new Exception ('No se puede violar la encapsulación');
    }
```

Haciendo esto ya no es posible otorgar de forma arbitraría una propiedad no deseada al objeto:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: No se puede violar la encapsulación in source_file.php:30
Stack trace:
#0 source_file.php(41): Objeto->__set('fakeProperty', 'Esta propiedad ...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in source_file.php on line 30
```

El Manual de PHP no menciona nada de esto, por lo que pregunto: **¿Cuál es la verdadera utilidad de los métodos mágicos `__set` y `__get`  en PHP?**

> **NOTA:** Me parece que la pregunta podría tener una amplia utilidad de cara a una programación en PHP que respete los principios de la
>   POO. Agradecería una respuesta que sea canónica y que se base en la
>   experiencia con estos métodos, no en opiniones.

Comment: Me parece que una respuesta sin opiniones no puede ser muy amplia, ya que la principal función de los métodos mágicos __get and __set es como tu mismo lo mencionaste, el encapsulamiento de los atributos

Comment: @Sr1871 el Manual no lo dice así de claro, ni siquiera hace demostraciones al respecto. De ahí mi duda y mi sorpresa.

Comment: No lo dice así de claro, pero en esa misma pestaña que pusiste más arriba mencionan siempre el uso de los métodos para propiedades inaccesibles, es decir un get o un set como otros lenguajes que encapsulan propiedades. incluso en el ejemplo que ponen debajo me parece que sin mencionar el encapsulamiento directamente lo dan a entender.

Comment: @Sr1871, pero esas son contribuciones de los usuarios. Me extraña que eso no esté documentado de forma *oficial* por llamarlo de alguna manera.

Comment: @A.Cedano ¿puede que esto sea lo que estés buscando? http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set Como han comentado ya, parece ser exclusivamente una forma de establecer manejadores en el acceso a propiedades inaccesibles.

Comment: @A.Cedano, leyendo el manual, me parece que esta bastante claro para que sirven los métodos en cuestión, como así también que el "overloading" en `PHP` es distinto al de otros lenguajes de programación. En tu ejemplo, no se esta violando la ["encapsulación"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulamiento_(inform%C3%A1tica)), ya que no se tiene acceso a datos "privados". Te soy sincero, me parece que la pregunta no esta del todo clara, y de cierta forma esta usando información equivocada.

Comment: @Marcos gracias por tu comentario. Aunque si leemos lo que dice el enlace que has compartido, el *encapsulamiento*  es definido más o menos así: *es el ocultamiento del estado, es decir, de los datos miembro de un objeto de manera que **solo se pueda cambiar mediante las operaciones definidas para ese objeto**.* Si el objeto me permite crear de forma arbitraria (saltándome todos sus métodos) una `fakeProperty`, como he demostrado en el código de la pregunta, es evidente que se está violando a todas luces el principio de encapsulación.

Comment: @A.Cedano, si lees la frase completa dice: "_de los datos miembro de un objeto **de manera que solo se pueda cambiar mediante las operaciones definidas para ese objeto**_", es decir, se refiere a datos protegidos o privados. Insisto en que esta mal interpretado el concepto sobre el cual se esta hablando.

Comment: @Marcos, también dice esto: *El aislamiento protege a los datos asociados de un objeto contra su modificación por quien no tenga derecho a acceder a ellos*. Yo insisto, el hecho de poder crear una `fakeProperty` entra dentro del concepto de violación de la encapsulación. Es más, considero que es algo mucho más grave, porque puedes transformar totalmente un objeto, dándole un contenido totalmente distinto al original.

Comment: @A.Cedano, desde mi punto de vista estas "extendiendo" o "decorando" tu objeto lo cual no tiene nada que ver con romper el "encapsulamiento". No estas pisando, accediendo o modificando a propiedades propias o privadas del objeto.

Comment: @A.Cedano, "_Las variables de un objeto se localizan en el núcleo del objeto. Los métodos rodean y esconden al núcleo del objeto de otros objetos en el programa. **Al empaquetamiento de las variables de un objeto con la protección de sus métodos se le llama encapsulamiento.** _". En ningún momento se hace referencia a prohibir extender el objeto.

Comment: @Marcos, entonces según tú, ¿cómo se le podría **llamar** a esa (¿posibilidad? ¡!) de agregar una `fakeProperty` a un objeto del modo en que se hace en PHP? ¿A eso le llamas tú *extender*  el objeto? ¿Acaso eso no es contradictorio con la herencia, que es el modo legítimo para *extender* objetos? ¿De qué manera en lenguajes como Java se podría *extender* un objeto agregando propiedades de forma arbitraria?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84789/discussion-between-marcos-and-a-cedano).

Comment: Podrias validar los set o get con isset() asi solo podras asignar variables definidas y obtener tambien solo variables  existentes

Answer (score 1):

Los métodos mágicos __set y __get fueron introducidos en PHP5 y existen aun como una curiosidad del lenguaje, actualmente no es recomendado su uso por la siguientes razones:

- Imagina tienes que validar cada uno de los campos de un objeto usando el método mágico __set:

```
class contact
{
    private $phone;
    public void __set ( string $name , mixed $value )
    {
       if ($name === "phone"){
          //se valida el teléfono.   
       }
       // una por cada verificación 
    }
}
```

Tendrías un método horriblemente largo que hace un millón de cosas, rompiendo unas cuantas reglas en diseño además de ser poco práctico.

- El acceso a las propiedades privadas tienen que ser completamente controladas por el desarrollador, si no serían publicas.
- Los métodos mágicos son extremadamente lentos (te dejo una referencia: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634748/php-zend-say-avoid-magic-methods).
- Entre otras razones más estructurales.

En realidad no se tocan en los libro de PHP es porque no tienen ninguna utilidad real, hace años que por motivos de legibilidad, principio de única responsabilidad, entre otros, su uso ha sido deprecado, existen pero no se recomiendan.