# ¿Posible crear variables nuevas en objetos instanciados de otra clase?

Tags: php

¿Se podria crear una variable de clase una vez instanciada esta sin estar especificada en dicha clase original? Me explico: Tengo una clase View con una variable y una funcion (omito detalles de funcion para no confundir)

```
class View{
  private $_js; 

  public function setJs(array $js)
   ...
  }
```

Despues otro archivo donde se hereda esa clase. Además, vean que en este archivo se instancia la clase y en una funcion se accede a una funcion(setJs) de la clase pero tambien se accede a una variable que no existe en la clase original(titulo) y le asigna un valor ('Mi titulo'):

```
class postController extends View
{
  private $_var1;
  $this->_view = new View();

  public function nuevo() 
  {
    $this->_view->titulo = 'Mi titulo';
    $this->_view->setJs(array('nuevo'));
  }
```

¿Esto se puede hacer? Es decir, la variable 'titulo' no estaba declarada en la clase inicial. ¿Se puede declararar una vez instanciada la clase? 
Estoy haciendo esta pregunta porque estoy viendo un ejemplo mucho mas complicado que estoy resumiendo aquí y realiza este tipo de declaraciones de variables en objetos ya instanciados.

Comment: Sí, esto se puede hacer en PHP y se puede evitar también mediante los métodos mágicos. A mí particularmente no me gusta que esto ocurra, porque la clase no queda encapsulada. Si mal no recuerdo pregunté algo sobre ese tema hace un tiempo. A ver si lo encuentro.

Comment: En efecto, [esta es la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/194096/29967). Ahí mismo se explica una forma de evitar ese comportamiento mediante métodos mágicos que evitarían que se agreguen nuevas propiedades *ad hoc*  en la clase. En los comentarios a la pregunta hubo un debate interesante, por ejemplo @Marcos decía que realmente no se violaba el encapsulamiento. Creo que el tema da para mucho, pero luego se quedó ahí y no seguimos profundizando.

Comment: Bueno, yo pensaba que esto no se podía hacer pero parece que si. ¿Se puede evitar la declaracion externa de variables o funciones? Decias que con el metodo mágico __set se puede aunque "sergiosusa" aportó que no es muy recomendable usarlos (no entiendo porque si evitan desperdigar el código). ¿cómo usaría ese metodo magico __set? ¿Asi?: public function __set($_var1, $var2) {
       throw new Exception ('No se puede violar la encapsulación');
    }
Siendo var1 y var2 las variables de la clase? Por cierto, gracias por la respuesta. Ya me estaba volviendo loco buscando variables sin declarar.

Answer (score 4):

**Si** que se puede hacer, bueno mejor dicho PHP lo deja pasar (aunque emite un warning). Esto sucede porque al contrario que en por ejemplo Java, en PHP no es necesario declarar las variables explicitamente.

El problema es que esta nueva variable se declara como public, además de hacer más caótico el código y vulnerar las buenas practicas de la Programación Orientada a Objetos (¿Por qué es esto importante? La respuesta principal sería el [encapsulamiento](https://styde.net/encapsulacion-y-programacion-orientada-a-objetos-con-php/)). Por estas razones te aconsejaría que **No** lo hicieras.